# Concatenating string to char*

Tags: c++, string, scope

I am a C# developer and I find strange that when I run the following code in C++:

```
std::string original = "Hello";

std::string st = original + "World";
const char *c = st.c_str();

const char *c2 = (original + "World").c_str();

std::cout << "c  = '" << c << "'" << std::endl;
std::cout << "c2 = '" << c2 << "'" << std::endl;
```

I get the following output:

```
c  = 'HelloWorld'
c2 = ''
```

In C# a similar construct will result in `c` and `c2` having the same value ("Hello World"). My guess would be that the scope of the result of `(original + "World")` ends on the right `)`, so `c_str()` is called on an invalid input. Is that correct? Is there a better way of achieving this other than creating variables to hold temporary results?

Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that you have a pointer to a buffer that is invalidated after the object is destroyed. Try this instead `std::cout << "c2 = '" << (original + "World").c_str() << "'" << std::endl;`

Comment: @imreal http://ideone.com/ovt8Ls it works (both).

Comment: @VictorPolevoy: Such is the nature of undefined behavior.

Comment: @FredLarson yes, seems so.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy even if you see desired output that does not mean it  works

Comment: You can use the `std::string`s directly in `cout`. You do not have to use `c_str()`.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2013 (v120) on Windows 7 Enterprise

Comment: And I don't need to use the code above as is. I just posted a simplified version to highlight my issue. I need to use a `char*` because I'm marshalling between C++ and C#.

Comment: I don't see the purpose in drawing conclusions on what C++ should do based on what C# does. You know they're _different languages_, right?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit -- I certainly know that they are different! But I'm much less experienced in C++ than in C#, so the purpose of this question was exactly to understand those differences

Comment: It would be more constructive to learn how C++ works in isolation than to learn it as a function of differences from some other language.

Comment: If you're going to write C++, get a good C++ book ( [look for one here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?lq=1) )and learn it properly. C++ doesn't work like C#. C++ strings are NOT immutable. `string s = "Hello"; s += " World"; cout << s;" will print "Hello World".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My guess would be that the scope of the result of (original + "World") ends on the right ), so c_str() is called on an invalid input. Is that correct?

Not quite, but close. `c_str()` itself is fine, but that pointer become invalid after the end of the statement, so using `c2` afterwards leads to UB.

> Is there a better way of achieving this other than creating variables to hold temporary results?

You can assign it to const reference:

```
const std::string &ref = original + "World";
const char *c2 = ref.c_str();
```

But I don't think that any better than creating variable.

Answer (score 2):

'c2' here is initialized with a pointer into a temporary object that ceases to exist at the semicolon. Therefore this is undefined behavior. You'll need to use an intermediate variable:

```
const auto temp(original + "World");
const char* c2 = temp.c_str();
```

Comment: Additional comment: Coming from the C# world you are used to having your memory managed for you with garbage collection etc.   There you would end up with a reference to the temporary object so it would stick around.  In C++ you have to be much more aware of the lifetime of objects.